# Add a field to an existing document firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new field to an already existing document, but when i use "merge: true" it erase all the previous data.

Here is the document's creation:

```
await db.collection('projects').doc(JSON.stringify(project.orderId)).set(
    {
        'orderId': project.orderId,
        'name': project.name,
    }, { merge: true }
)
```

The result :

```
ID : {
    orderID: ID,
    name: "project"
}
```

And here is when i want to add the new field:

```
await db.collection('projects').doc(project.orderId).set(
    {
        'responsable': project.responsable,
    }, { merge: true }
)
```

```
ID : {
    responsable: "resp"
}
```

Comment: That should not happen. Can you log `project` and share what the object looks like ? Why are you using `stringify()` in first code snippet

Comment: Isn't it because for the first case you use `JSON.stringify(project.orderId)`for the doc ID and in the second case you use only `project.orderId`? Just to check... since we don't know what is `project.orderId`.

Comment: I've removed the `JSON.stringify` as it wasn't useful. It still erase the data but not every time

Comment: What do you mean by "erase the data but not every time"?

Comment: I found the problem, the second set of data had spaces before sometimes that's why it wasn't working every time. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please write an answer with your findings, so anyone who might find this question in the future can see the solution without having to read the comments.

Comment: Well i didn't found a real solution, i simply used String.replace(/\s+/g, '') to delete spaces that were before the text